# Closing a div when another opens

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table inside a `<div>` and I want to be able to open/close those `<div>`s wihtout having 2 open at the *same* time.

For now I can open/close the divs but I can't figure out how to close the previous one when I open another one. I know it is because of my script but I'm new to JS and would appreciate some help.

```js
//<![CDATA[
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible-service");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("activeContent");
    var contentCollapsible = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (contentCollapsible.style.maxHeight) {
      contentCollapsible.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      contentCollapsible.style.maxHeight = contentCollapsible.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
//]]>
```

```css
.collapsible-service {
  background-color: #2c3a57;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: ridge #d20000;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.activeContent,
.collapsible-service:hover {
  background-color: #4f6798;
}

.collapsible-service:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.activeContent:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.contentCollapsible {
  padding: 0px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible-service">Hourly Rate</button>
<div class="contentCollapsible">
  <div class="table-block  customer-service__block">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Services</th>
          <th>Timeframe</th>
          <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>General hourly rate</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>50.00$</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="collapsible-service">Complete Adjustment</button>
<div class="contentCollapsible">
  <div class="table-block  customer-service__block">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Services</th>
          <th>Timeframe</th>
          <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>General hourly rate</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>50.00$</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actualy calling anything that would close other divs. You need to find that one that is already active and close it.

Something like this

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible-service");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var prev = document.getElementsByClassName("activeContent");
    if(prev[0] != null && prev[0] != this){
         prev[0].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
         prev[0].classList.remove("activeContent");
    }

    this.classList.toggle("activeContent");
    var contentCollapsible = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (contentCollapsible.style.maxHeight){
      contentCollapsible.style.maxHeight = null;
    } 
    else 
    {
      contentCollapsible.style.maxHeight = contentCollapsible.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

See the Pen [LJLwOp](https://codepen.io/Kamil-Folwarczny/pen/LJLwOp/) by Kamil Netopejr Folwarczny ([@Kamil-Folwarczny](https://codepen.io/Kamil-Folwarczny)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: Works great thank you ! I understand the logic behind your code so it's really helpful.

Comment: Glad to hear. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Create another function to get all the elements with class `contentCollapsible` and iterate through them and set the style of `maxHeight` to null

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible-service");
var i;

function closeAllElement() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.contentCollapsible').forEach(function(item) {
    item.style.maxHeight = null;
  })

}

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    closeAllElement()
    this.classList.toggle("activeContent");
    var contentCollapsible = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (contentCollapsible.style.maxHeight) {
      contentCollapsible.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      contentCollapsible.style.maxHeight = contentCollapsible.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible-service {
  background-color: #2c3a57;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: ridge #d20000;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.activeContent,
.collapsible-service:hover {
  background-color: #4f6798;
}

.collapsible-service:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.activeContent:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.contentCollapsible {
  padding: 0px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible-service">Hourly Rate</button>
<div class="contentCollapsible">
  <div class="table-block  customer-service__block">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Services</th>
          <th>Timeframe</th>
          <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>General hourly rate</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>50.00$</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="collapsible-service">Complete Adjustment</button>
<div class="contentCollapsible">
  <div class="table-block  customer-service__block">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Services</th>
          <th>Timeframe</th>
          <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>General hourly rate</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>50.00$</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```